# Facebook Login CallbackManager FacebookCallback not called?

Tags: android, facebook

- I trying to login with LoginButton but the login callbacks are not being called.(LoginButton is in a Fragment) .
- FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize is called in the Application onCreate
- No Callbacks are called after login is completed.
  Here is the Code:

Activity:

```
public class FrameActivity extends BaseActivity {

 public static CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize is called in the Application onCreate

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
}
```

Fragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");
    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(FrameActivity.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


}
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to initialize FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() in your activity and check. And put Log in onSuccess(), onCancel(), onError() methods

Comment: No, its not working with it too. Please help. Yes I have put logs ,and placed debug points, (removed from the code pasted here)

Comment: can you post your code of facebook login with fragement ...if it is working as i am not able to login into facebook with above like code

Comment: I was missing facebookBTN.setFragment(this); for the whole thing to work, forgot that you need to do this for fragments

Comment: try this answer worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/38158506/4685534

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this:

1. Init `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` in fragment's `onCreateView()`.
2. Next line init `callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()`;
3. Implement on `onActivityResult()` in Fragment class.
4. Add your `callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`
   in fragment `onActivityResult()`.

Make sure remove `FacebookInit()` and `callbackManager` from activity.

Comment: Adding callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in fragment onActivityResult. worked it for me. Thanks alot .

Comment: So, how could i get loginResult without using FacebookCallback<LoginResult> ?

Comment: i am implementing these code but can't result me ...i want to add "publish_actions" permission in fragment with LoginManager after fb login

Comment: Please note that if you are using logInWithReadPermissions(.. , ..) in Fragment, pass (this) as first parameter, instead of getActivity(), because there are 2 methods one takes Fragment the other Activity.

Comment: If you're calling from fragment, also sure the Activity the fragment is in calls super.onActivityResult() in its onActivityResult() as well. That was my problem.

Answer (score 19):

```
loginButton.setFragment(this);
```

This line is already in the question. But just wanted to write this for any other developers who over look.

If you are using FB login button in a fragment make sure you add this to your onCreateView method. This ensures the call back to go to Fragment rather than going to your activity.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!  I had an issue where after logging in, the fb login dialog would not close.  I've been trying to figure this out for hours.  It turns out that I've been using the fb LoginButton which pops up its own dialog on click, and I was also popping up a different dialog.  Your comment got me to realize that the fb LoginButton actually has some logic of its own built int.

Comment: @pickle_inspector I'm glad it helped. I over looked that line of code and had to spend hours to figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 10):

> **for older versions:**

change the method as below:

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {

        com.facebook.Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else
    {
        com.facebook.Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }

}
```

> **UPDATE: for v2.3, from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3):**

You add the callback to your activity or fragment's onCreate() method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                 // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                 // App code   
            }
});
}
```

If login succeeds, the `LoginResult` parameter has the new `AccessToken`, and the most recently granted or declined permissions.

**You don't need a registerCallback for login to succeed, you can choose to follow current access token changes with the `AccessTokenTracker` class described below.**

Then in `onActivityResult()` forward the login results to the `callbackManager` created in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Every activity and fragment that you integrate with the FacebookSDK Login or Share should forward `onActivityResult` to the callbackManager.

Comment: I was reading facebook sdk documentation, and found out that:
Session Removed - AccessToken, LoginManager and CallbackManager classes supercede and replace functionality in the Session class.

I want to do it with LoginManager,or CallbackManager. 
Please telkl me how can i do with the latest specification

Comment: com.facebook.Session class is not in the latest sdk ( I am using maven remote repository- Android Studio)

Comment: you have not registered callbackmanager for login. see the updated answer

Comment: @user3450413 You mean that I don't have to use LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback as we can update callbackmanager in onActivityResult via callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);?

Answer (score 2):

Take also into account that if you have two callback managers for two different operations (like login and share) the first one that receives onActivityResult can receive the second's callback and vice versa. That behaviour can also make your callback not be called.

Answer (score 2):

if in Fragment this is important `loginButton.setFragment(this);`

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me

> Initialize callback manager

```
CallbackManager sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

> Create method to register callback

```
private void configureFacebookAppInviteCallBack(){

    AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(InviteHomeFragment.this);
                        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,
                                new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                                        Log.d("rht", "Invitation Sent Successfully");
                                        CommonUtils.getInstance().showToast("50");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancel() {
                                        Log.d("rht", "Error Occured in facebook invite ");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                                        if(e!=null) {
                                            Log.d("rht", "Error Occured in facebook invite ");
                                        }else{
                                            Log.d("rht", "Error Occured in facebook invite");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


}
```

> Implement onActivityResult.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.v("rht", "onActivityResult called requestCode "+requestCode+" resultCode "+resultCode);

        sCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: as per new API, `startActivityForResult(..)` is deprecated, so we have to get rid of `onActivityResult()`, so we can't send and get `requestCode`, according to new solution for this, you can't complete `sCallbackManager..` line, now look at this image - prnt.sc/1wpspcz, do you have knowledge about this problem, then please tell us..

Comment: if you can't understand my problem correctly then just update your code from `startActivityForResult(..)` to new alternate code and try to complete `sCallbackManager..` line, and also look at this image https://prnt.sc/1wpspcz (this error will occurs after applying new alternate code)

Answer (score 0):

I spent ~3 hours to figure out I were misunderstanding of using facebook API.

```
    void someInitCode() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        callAPI();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    }

                });

}
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) callAPI();
            else callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else {
            Log.d("hole", "not ok");
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The original call didn't put `onSuccess()` code into separate function `callAPI()`, so it never call API even though already login success. The reason is because loggedin and re-login will not go inside `onSuccess()` !

The workaround I found is check access token and separate the call to `callAPI()` in both `onSuccess()` and `onActivityResult()`.