# Not getting a callback in onActivityResult while trying to integrate Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been trying to integrate Facebook login with Android, login to facebook happens, however I am not getting a callback in onActivityResult. I have already followed this:
[Facebook Login CallbackManager FacebookCallback not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557486/facebook-login-callbackmanager-facebookcallback-not-called)
However, my problem remains unsolved. Here is a code snippet:

```
@Override
protected FragmentPresenter getFragmentPresenter() {
    return presenter;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    view.setClickable(true);
    setupView(view);
    //FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext());
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
    loginFacebook.setFragment(this);

    loginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK);
            getActivity().finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            getActivity().setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            getActivity().finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //Handle Exception
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `callbackManager.onActivityResult` before the `super.onActivityResult` line?